# How to redirect each type of user to a different page when access is denied?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.3

In my app I have 3 roles of Users (user, admin, non logged user), and I want to redirect them to different pages when access is denied. How to do that?

In time, what $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller'); means? I didn't understand this in cake docs.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have it in a IF statement, but perhaps someone else can suggest a more CakePHP specific method..

```
if($user === 'Admin') {
   //Admin Redirect
   $redirectController = 'admin';
   $redirectMethod = 'admin_index';
} elseif ($user === 'User') {
   //User Redirect
   $redirectController = 'user';
   $redirectMethod = 'index';
} else {
  //Not logged in
  $redirectController = 'SomeController';
  $redirectMethod = 'someMethod';
}

$this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect = array(
        'controller' => $redirectController,
        'action' => $redirectMethod 
    );
```

`$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');` means that the Authorization is done at the Controller level. I believe you can change where authorization is carried out using this.

Comment: Just to check, Will I use this code on AppController::beforeFilter(); right?

Comment: Yeah, it would be in the `AppController::beforeFilter()`