# How to use unauthorizedRedirect to redirect user of different role to their respective page?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my app I have a user with 3 different roles and each one with their own respective page that they can visit. I would like to redirect them to their own respective home page when they try to access any pages that they should not be viewing, but are unable to do so.

I found the below thread with a very similar problem, but after modifying and putting the code in AppController::beforefilter, I am unable to get the desired result.

[How to redirect each type of user to a different page when access is denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059455/how-to-redirect-each-type-of-user-to-a-different-page-when-access-is-denied)

Updated with code from the thread above:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $user_role = $this->Auth->user('role');

    if ($user_role == "admin")
    {
        $redirectController = 'Pages';
        $redirectMethod     = 'adminhome';
    }
    elseif ($user_role == "teacher")
    {
        $redirectController = 'Pages';
        $redirectMethod     = 'teacherhome';
    }
    elseif ($user_role == "studentparent")
    {
        $redirectController = 'Pages';
        $redirectMethod     = 'parenthome';
    }

    $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect = array(
        'controller' => $redirectController,
        'action'     => $redirectMethod,
        'prefix'     => false
    );

}
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: hi, the version is 3.4.5. i have updated the thread with code, thanks

Comment: What is the result you are getting?